# Find the smallest multiple in Project Euler - whats wrong with my code?

Tags: python

Question: What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

And here's my code:

```
n = 20
numbers = range (1, n+1)
is_divisible = False

while not is_divisible:
    for m in numbers:
        if n % m !=0:
            n += n
            break
        else:
            if m != max(numbers):
                continue
        is_divisible = True

print (n)
```

When I set n>=4, the loop runs forever, while there's no problems whatsoever when 1<=n<=3. So I wonder what's the problem ...

Comment: Find LCM of 1 to 20.

Comment: Yes I know it's about LCM, but I think there are many algorithms to find it (without using any built-in functions for LCM)

Comment: What I did is choose the maximum out of the numbers (in this case 20), and check 20, 40, 60, etc. to test whether they're the common multiples of 1-20 (or 2-19 actually), because the answer must be a multiple of 20, so the result can be obtained quicker. What bothers me is the program gives right answer in an instant if n <= 3, but for n >= 4 the program runs forever. So I want to know why does it lead to endless loop at all.

Comment: So instead of knowing how the problem can be done, I just want to know why it was done wrongly.

Comment: "...and check 20, 40, 60, etc." -- what you're actually checking is "20, 40, 80, 160" (doubling it each time) -- just adding a 2 to the factors -- in some cases (like n=4, testing for divisibility by 3) no matter how many times you double n, you'll never get it evenly divisible by 3.

Comment: In other words, change the first line to `N = 20`, insert a line `n=N` under that, and change `n += n` to `n += N` and test it.

Comment: Oh you're right! I see what's wrong about the code. Now that I changed the line n += n to n+=max(num) and it works. However, the code works for n = 1 to n = 18, but starting from 19 the result is generated ridiculously slowly, I guess it's not an effective algorithm after all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Because the answer blows up so quickly, when n = 20, the answer is in the order of 10^8, so scanning 20 every time is ineffective. Without using any built-in functions (LCM or GCD, etc.), how can the algorithm be made more effective?

Comment: you can just duplicate the functionality -- for example, create a factoring function that accepts an integer and returns it's prime factorization (maybe in a dict), then do that for each number 1-20.  Then figure out what factors you need and the appropriate power for each.  Lastly, "unfactorize"/multiply these factors into a final integer answer.